# How do I call a Lisp function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, common-lisp

I wrote a program in Common Lisp (CLISP 2.49) to play connect 4 against a human player. I am using javascript and jquery for the GUI. I want to call the AIMove() function from javascript (maybe using ajax?). It takes the current state of the board (a list of 7 lists) as argument and returns a single integer (the row in which to insert the new chip). I can not figure out how to call the lisp function from the javascript code. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. How are you loading CLISP into the browser?

Comment: I am running CLISP in my computer. I want javascript to make the call to the CLISP function for it to run on my computer and then return the output for the javascript to show it in the browser. Does that make any sense? I am really quite inexperiences in front-end programming.

Comment: This is actually a back-end programming issue. You need to figure out how to run the CLISP code as a CGI program on the server.

Comment: When you say you're running it in your computer, is that the computer that's the server or the client? Javascript can't run external programs on the client machine. It can use AJAX to connect to scripts that are configured on the server.

Comment: The only language that runs in the browser is Javascript. It may be possibly to compile your Lisp program to javascript and then run that in the browser. https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/ Javascript cannot call other runtimes in the browser either

Comment: Im not sure. Im sorry, I really am a beginner here. Its for a school project, i wrote the lisp code and the javascript code separetely, but I have no idea how to send data from one to the other. If it is any help, here is the repository https://github.com/rodolfoocampo/Connect-4

Comment: @elliotE Is that a good way to run my lisp code? Wouldn't it be slow?

Comment: Think of it this way: when someone views your website there is no way for them to run your Lisp program, but they can definitely run Javascript. It might actually run fairly well because it is compiled, but the only other alternative is to have your website communicate with a server that runs the lisp code and then responds back to the website.

Comment: I see. Well, for now I only need to run it on my computer (it is a school project). Would you recommend that I compile it in javascript or create the client-server connection?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you run the Lisp code as a server and connect to the server from the browser.

I did this when I implemented a [portable inspector](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/inspect.lisp): the browser displays the content of the lisp structure when the HTTP backend is used..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "using Ajax". But that means:

1. Get a Lisp webserver to serve your app (a lot of folks use Hunchentoot)
2. Now send an AJAX request from your JS client to some endpoint you listen for in the webserver with whatever parameters you need to convey the game state. The code handling that endpoint calls your Lisp function and puts the response in the body.
3. In the client JS handler of the Ajax request you receive the Lisp result in the body of the response and process as needed.